# Angular PWA App Basic Problems

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am getting very basic problems in Angular PWA app. Once cached app is not accessible on refresh and even on offline .

I have narrow downed to it in a simple app.

1. Downloaded Basic Angular 6 Sample (https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip) .
2. Added Latest PWA support by running it ng add @angular/pwa .
3. ng build --prod .
4. uploaded the dist folder content on my github repo
   (vimmubansal.github.io).
5. Now check app on https://vimmubansal.github.io/
6. After few seconds (when app is cached) , please refresh app, then you will see "This site can not be reached" or be offline..you will not get a cached app which you should get .

Note: But in Incognito mode, it is working fine with no such issue .

Please help .

Comment: Oh, that's a weird problem! This will probably not help, but do you have anything hardcoded in your app with HTTP (not https) ? I saw some mixed content errors

Comment: Is the root of your app @ /dashboard ? I'm not sure if this will fix it, but you may want to try putting that in your angular.json file

Comment: No code written here. I am getting this issue in any of PWA app. Unable to understand why same app is working fine in incognito mode but in normal mode something is breaking.  App is a standard example of angular tutorial. dashboard is default route

Comment: This may help. Try deploying a .htaccess file to your root folder as mentioned here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19009

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your web-app running in only one tab of your browser (close any other tab if exists).
2. Close Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

when you run app use "http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist" command, you can install http-server for angular and in browser use http://127.0.0.1:8080/ link

Answer (score 0):

**go to link :** [Getting started with PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)

run command in angular CLI : `ng add @angular/pwa`

go to below links.

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#assetgroups

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#resources